# Why isn't Adobe Acrobat's 'Map Colors' fixup changing a PDF's text colors?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Please see the screenshot beneath. I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 2019.010.20064. The PDF in question can be downloaded [here](https://mega.nz/file/3pZzEKJC#ApxrrU08OuH18OuxvXGao9r5jp2b43lVCFJ5WFu_Tok).

I'm trying to use [mrserge's method](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005) to convert the book's default (C, M, Y, K) = (99%, 98%, 18%, 6%) (ie dark purple) to [(90, 0, 90, 0) (green)](https://www.colorhexa.com/1aff1a). After I click 'OK' and click 'Fix', Adobe Acrobat executes the fixup, but the color fails to change.

[image]

Comment: Workaround (brute force) without acrobat pro. Uncompress the file, `pdftk file.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress`, search for the string with the color (it is slightly different `0.181 0.181 0.488`) and change it `sed 's/0.181 0.181 0.488/0.102 1.000 0.102/g' uncompressed.pdf > newfile.pdf`. It is in lines as `/CS0 cs 0.181 0.181 0.488  scn` or with SCN instead if scn... You may find interesting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584228/how-to-change-all-colours-in-a-pdf-to-their-respective-complimentary-colours-ho)

Comment: @Hastur Thanks! I was yearning for a solution with Adobe Acrobat Pro though.

Comment: It is for this that I have not (yet) posted it as an answer, but just as a comment. It works, but I don't know if the problem resides in the fact that the violet color I found is sightly different from the one you posted, moreover in RGB normalized to 1 and not in CMYK, or because it is repeated for each page (after the `uncompress` operation). BTW seldom I've to live up to my nickname and post caotic answers as the above one...You're welcome.

Comment: Another thing: I suppose the color you wanted to substitute was (C, M, Y, K) = (63%, 63%, 0%, 51%). Did you tried with these values?

Comment: @Hastur Sorry. I don't understand your last comment. I input  "(90, 0, 90, 0)" for this is the CMYK that I desire.

Comment: I like to give numbers ... Hastur is a kaos deity ... Seriously, try the ones I gave you. I opened page 4 with another program that gave me those values for that color (63 63 0 51%), not yours. Give it a try, maybe your procedure works but you need to insert different values ...Inside the uncompressed PDF colors are stored as rgb (0..1, ...) as in the posted answer. Try rgb as source color model.

Answer (score 0):

#### Changing a color with *bare hands*

I cannot provide instructions on Adobe Acrobat Pro, however, I can suggest a procedure with open source programs and some specific hints valid for the OP document, but maybe also useful for the other readers.

A PDF file, once uncompressed, is somehow [human-readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Technical_overview).

- So let's first uncompress the file with [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/):

  ```
  pdftk OriginalFile.pdf output Uncompressed.pdf uncompress
  ```
- Then we can start taking a look inside, manually(!) making the changes ... ok not really manually.
  We want to replace a color throughout the document.
  In the OP case and in the file after the decompression, the color is stored as rgb (0..1,0..1,0..1).
- Instead of finding something like (C, M, Y, K) = (63%, 63%, 0%, 51%) we find the something like (r,g,b)=(0.181 0.181 0.488). In the OP file the occurencies are lines like

  ```
  /CS0 cs 0.181 0.181 0.488  scn
  ```
- To be honest there is a lot of them (2048). With a single command we will replace them all at once. Here we use `sed` **s**ubstituting each occurence of the string `0.181 0.181 0.488` with the string `0.102 1.000 0.102`, **g**lobally (on all the file). Of course it is always possible to use any editor able to deal with binary files:

  ```
  sed 's/0.181 0.181 0.488/0.102 1.000 0.102/g' uncompressed.pdf > newfile.pdf
  ```

To selectively replace that color string only in some places, we need to identify where.

---

**Notes**

There are several different occurrences of that color string that act differently on the text.

```
   1 /CS1 cs 0.181 0.181 0.488  scn   # Logo on page 5 
  96 /CS0 CS 0.181 0.181 0.488  SCN   # No visual effect
 826 /CS0 cs 0.181 0.181 0.488  scn   # Headers, page n., some(not all) other parts
1095 0.181 0.181 0.488  scn           # The other text
```

It is possible to act singularly on them, e.g. with

```
sed 's/CS0 cs 0.181 0.181 0.488  scn/CS0 cs 0.900 0.000 0.000  scn/g' uncomp.pdf
```